# when a container needs to be a clickable link

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm not quite sure the best way to deal with this situation. Here's a hypothetical situation:

```
<a href="/my-page/">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-image: url('images/myimage.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat; position: relative;">
        <div style="line-height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">
            <span>My Clickable Box</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

So in this situation, I have a container with another container positioned at the bottom for the actual text...but I need the entire box to be clickable.

As we all know, an anchor tag does not do well when you tell it to be a specific height or width...so you pretty much rely on the inner content to do so.

I don't know, I'm at a bit of a loss on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change its display to `block` or `inline-block` you can size it, no need to use divs inside which I'm pretty sure is invalid.

```
<a style="display:inline-block;width: 150px; height: 150px; background-image: url('images/myimage.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat; position: relative;" href="/my-page/">
    <span>My Clickable Box</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned above ... divs inside of an anchor tag is a "no no" ... not sure why.

Comment: You cant have a block element (div) inside a inline element (a)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the div that needs to be clickable inside the anchor tag, and set the size on the div. The whole div will then be clickable as it lives inside the link.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it a issue using a anchor as a main element?

Comment: Don't see why it would be. If you're resetting the browsers default css you should be able to completely control how it displays. I'd think it's more a matter of bad form than can't be done.

Comment: Looking at your html again the only real problem I can see is the position:absolute on the div. If your using that for positioning, you would just need to nest some divs - so <div style="position:absolute"><a href="#"><div>my clickable content with styles to fill the parent div</div></a></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can style the anchor just like you would the divs, and then the entire area is clickable. E.g.

```
<a href="/my-page/" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-image: url('images/myimage.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat; position: relative; line-height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">My Clickable Box
```

Comment: Anchor tags don't respond to height and width properly.

Comment: @dcolumbus, they do. Anchor tags can be sized like other elements. The only difference is that anchor tags are initially displayed as inline elements. You have to display them as block or linline-block to be able to size them

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple javascript click event listener:

```
<div id="myDiv000">
    (...)
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("myDiv000").addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.location.href = "/my-page";
    });
    document.getElementById("myDiv000").style.cursor = "pointer";
</script>
```